# Product of complete sets of representatives of the cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we have the subgroups $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$ (not necessarily normal), all finite groups. 
Denote $\mathcal{R}^G_H$ be a complete set of representatives of the cosets of $G$ in $H$, and similarly for the other combinations.

Is it then true that: 
$$
\mathcal{R}^G_H = \mathcal{R}^G_K \cdot \mathcal{R}^K_H, 
$$
At least that the product $\mathcal{R}^G_K \cdot \mathcal{R}^K_H$ (i.e. the pairwise product of every pair of elements from those sets) is a complete set of representatives of the cosets of $G$ in $H$?

I didn't manage to prove it and I'm not sure if it's true in the first place.

Comment: Yes it's true that the set of products of elements of a right transversal of $K$ in $H$ and of a right transversal of $H$ in $G$ is a right transversal of $H$ in $G$. The proof is routine. But it is not necessarily true that every right transversal of $H$ in $G$ has that form.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, the first fact that you mentioned is what I need. I was struggling with the proof, but I think I understand it now. We need to verify two things: (1) Every element $g \in G$ can be written as $g = r_1r_2h$ for $r_1 \in R^G_K$ and $r_2 \in R^K_H$, and (2) if $g = r_1r_2h = r'_1r'_2h'$, then $r'_1 = r_1$ and $r_2 = r'_2$ (again with $r_1,r'_1 \in R^G_K$ and $r_2,r'_2 \in R^K_H$). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's right. First write $g=r_1k$ with $k \in K$ and then write $k=r_2h$ with $h \in H$, giving $g=r_1r_2h$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I would very much like this question to come out of the unanswered queue; would you be willing to cobble these three comments into an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H \le K \le G$ and let $R_H^K$ and $R_K^G$ be right transversals of $H$ in $K$ and of $K$ in $G$, respectively (i.e. $K = \cup_{k \in R_H^K} Hk$ and $G = \cup_{g \in R_K^G} Kg$). Then $R_H^KR_K^G = \{ k \in R_H^K,g \in R_K^G \}$ is a right transversal of $H$ in $G$.

It is immediately clear that $G = \cup _{ k \in R_H^K,g \in R_K^G } Hkg$.

If $Hk_1g_1=Hk_2g_2$ then, $g_1 = g_2$, and hence $Hk_1=Hk_2$, so $k_1=k_2$.